# Dimensional modeling two dimension are related to the same country dimension

Tags: data-warehouse, snowflake-schema, dimensional-modeling

Hello Everyone So I'm building a data warehouse (snowflake schema) and I have an owner dimension and contact dimension and both of them are related to location dimension.
in the fact table I want to add an owner location key and a contact location id.
Do i have to use a role playing dimension ( create a contact location dimension and an owner location dimension) or I can use an only location dimension that contains both information ?
Thank you ;)

Comment: A role playing dimension is a single dimension that is taking more than one logical role - so I'm not sure what you then mean by creating contact/owner location dimensions, as you're not actually creating anything and therefore your 2 options are actually the same thing

Comment: Thank you that's clear but I don't know what to do in this case I need to link owners dimension and contact dimension with same location dimension and I'm not sure that's a correct action. I have an owner dimension, a contact dimension and a location dimension and in the fact I will have owner key, contact key and location key but the location key will be for owner or contact ?

Comment: If you need both locations. then you would have 2 location keys in your fact table, referencing the different locations of the owner and contact

Comment: Well I think that can solve the issue thanks @NickW ;)